# How do you check when a key is mapped in vim?

Tags: vim

I have a few mappings in vim for moving between splits set in my .vimrc,

```
nnoremap <C-j> <C-w>j
nnoremap <C-k> <C-w>k
nnoremap <C-h> <C-w>h
nnoremap <C-l> <C-w>l
```

All of these work except for `<C-j>`, which I suspect is being remapped in one of my plugins.  I'd like to find out where, but I'm not sure how.  Is there a way to find "where was `<C-j>` last mapped?"

Comment: If no better way comes out, I would grep for the mapping in my plugins folder

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
:verbose nnoremap <c-j>
```

should help.